# Keeping souls happy for eternity

Tags: religion

In my universe, when good people die they go to paradise. There they have everything they want. However, because they have been carefully selected for their goodness, they won't ask for anything that will harm themselves, any other person or anything living thing.

The problem now is keeping them entertained for eternity. They must be in a continual state of happiness, but no drugs or alcohol allowed - that would be bad under my regime.
Now I have to deal with boredom. Given that there is a huge yet finite number of skills or hobbies for them to undertake, there will come a time when they inevitably have to repeat something.

As long as the options for amusement are finite, how can I stop my paradise from driving its inhabitants crazy eventually?

---

**Note** Please ask for missing details before answering - Thanks.

---

**Conditions**

As souls they don't require sleep, so they are forever conscious.

These are immortal souls so they cannot commit suicide.

They are 'blessed' with infinite memory.

They never die and paradise lasts forever.

The souls appear to themselves as perfect humans, living in an idealised material world. They can 'eat' delicious food, but this is illusory because they have no digestive system. They can undertake illusory physical activities and have the resources to do so. They are always healthy.

If they leap from a high place or shoot themselves, no harm is done and no pain is felt.

Comment: Are your souls immaterial, and as such, require no material things for happiness, or they are manifested in material bodies, which require more or less the same maintenance as the normal human bodies?

Comment: @Alexander - Added to list - does this answer your question?

Comment: not completely. For example, when the soul eats, does the meal it consumes leaves it fully satisfied, or there are back thoughts like "It's not the same as the real thing"?

Comment: @Alexander - Food will taste good and feel good afterwards but is optional. They can do without it eternally or eat as much as they want. They will maintain an ideal shape according to their beliefs and customs, regardless of diet.

Comment: A good person wouldn't ask for anything that would harm themselves? No sugar, alcohol, tobacco, driving privileges, sleeping in the sun, walking on suspension bridges, or having children? Really? :-)

Comment: Also, not to be a pest, but how is this not an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) or, worse, opinion-based? What makes one person happy won't another. This is a very subjective question.

Comment: @JBH I also think that way; It's based on a lot of wild imagination, and a lot of assumptions can be made. Just thinking about how many religions handle or avoid this issue makes me ponder about that. It's a vital, interesting and kinda eternal topic in philosophy (how to be happy?), but we may never see a definitive answer.

Comment: According to [The Good Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_Place), you can't... Erm... yeah, spoilers... sorry...)

Comment: My suggestion: Give them social media.

Answer (score 7):

### Boredom Serves A Purpose - For Mortals

Boredom is necessary in mortal beings.  *You* can starve to death, if you're too engrossed in what you're doing to go and find something to eat.  You could even grow too weak gather food, long before you actually die.  (Sure, we're talking hunter-gatherer instincts, but we are largely indistinguishable from our hunter-gatherer ancestors, except for being better-fed, and taller because we are better-fed.)

### Boredom serves no purpose for an immortal soul?

If you're unkillable, and have no need to eat, nor to procreate...  There is no (physically) compelling need for you to ever get bored.  What would require an immortal soul to experience boredom?  Want to replay your favorite video game a million times?  Fine.  Want to memorize every brush stroke in the Mona Lisa?  Cool.  Want to watch a video of spackle drying, played on a loop for a trillion years?  Um, I guess, if that's your thing.

If you want to autistically obsess about the evolutionary paths of each dinosaur sub-species, and tell all your immortal-soul buddies for the 477-billionth time about the weird reasons for the archaeopteryx line to gain flight, lose it (I made that up), gain it again...  And lose it again as a sub-line evolved into kiwis!  As long as your immortal buddies get a turn to tell about how many times William of Orange improbably escaped death, or what percentage of the human population was descended from Genghis Khan in each successive century, great.

If you're more the type to have a dressy cocktail party that lasts forever (with non-alcoholic drinks, of course), I'm pretty sure you'll find some other immortals who are up for that, too.

**Spiritually useful boredom?**

Me, I'm the actually-autistic-enough to not get bored of certain kinds of video games, which is why I largely can't let myself play those kinds of games.  This is part of the reason I've pondered on the subject of boredom, and concluded that it exists for the reason of impelling us to do something useful with our finite time and need for physical nourishment.

(If you believe in a God) God made us in such a way that, for the time being, we CANNOT fritter away an eternity obsessively focused on one thing, because we are bound by the leash of ever-impending starvation, and other limits.  (I think I need to go to the bathroom soon - for example.)

Maybe there's something useful to do in Heaven, which we can scarcely imagine now, which a motivated individual will find engaging.  Certainly, if heaven is nothing but a nice club for the really well-behaved, there's no reason we should still be composed in such a manner that boredom is a thing.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to do more with them than just entertain them.  Entertainment may last for a while, but assuming it's finite you'll eventually run into the problems you mentioned.  The only way to get around this is to employ the members of paradise to make new entertainment, effectively creating infinite entertainment.  The creative process itself is entertaining for many, so having souls in paradise making videogames, books, television, music and other media is the only way to prolong this for eternity.  The number of videogames is technically infinite in the same way that numbers are, because you can always take the same videogame and then make it incrementally longer.  The same applies to other forms of media as well, so the amount of entertainment is going to be infinite.

Comment: Spoken like someone anxiously awaiting the release of the newest installment of half-life. ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Sports!**

They watch sports.  And play sports!  They all have rocking bodies and cant get hurt so the chariot crashes are all good and no-one wears pads or helmets for football.  Some sports too dangerous to play on Earth are a hoot for these folks: alpine mountain tag, dynamite go carts, etc.  When a dude gets thrown high in the air while running with the bulls you can laugh loudly and not feel bad, and his pants don't rip, because he was not wearing any.

**Sex!**

The rocking bodies part, and cant get hurt, and always healthy. Plus they are good people so there are no jerks; everything is consensual and fun.

**Music!**
In between the sporting events and the sex there is a sweet concert every night.

**Barbeque!**  And there is beer, but no alcohol, so it is just cold fizzy beer tasting beverage to wash down the barbecue.  That is just fine.

Comment: You've answered (the same)  twice!

Comment: I guess I was enthusiastic.  Actually I dont have to guess.  I deleted the other one because it didnt have beer.

Comment: This reminds me of the book "A Rose-Red City" by Dave Duncan.

Answer (score 1):

**Happiness is subjective. But with proper curation, a collection of eternally happy souls is possible.**

For some people, happiness is their natural state. For some, happiness is always fleeting and fragile. While this may correlate with one's "goodness", it would be fundamentally wrong to assume that all virtuous people are naturally happy, and all sinful people are naturally sour.

Thus, with a proper selection of souls which are not only virtuous, but naturally happy and complacent with the high standards of your paradise, an always happy society should be possible.

I am not addressing the boredom that may arise from this lifestyle. Let's just say that your chosen ones are not susceptible to it.

Answer (score 1):

**"They are 'blessed' with infinite memory."**

You mean cursed. The true secret to happiness is forgetfulness. Old experiences become new. Old enemies becomes new friends. Old haunts become new destinations.

Perfect memory would be an absolute nightmare and you could not ever keep someone happy for eternity.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. For dementia patients, they can play the same movie over and over again, they never remember it. Every time is a brand new experience. True happiness is not remembering.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid under the listed conditions, there's no way to achieve this without meddling with the soul's psychology. Infinity is a long time. Yes, far longer than consuming every piece of entertainment ever written, filmed or sung in the history of the universe (including fanfics). Even longer than reading all that plus all made up versions that overlap and crossover with each other in every conceivable way, no matter how many hundreds of trillions of years it will take to read through all of that - there's still a lot of infinity left waiting before you - **all** of it, in fact. Even a human being who is *forced* to be happy (they constantly generate spiritual analogue to serotonin for example and aren't getting used to it) will simply go mad from the sheer vastness that is infinity. Due to how our memory and cognition work (Ever noticed how as you age, whole years appear to get by faster? I can *swear* it was 2015 just a little while ago!), soon enough whole *geological epochs* will be flying by in a blink of an eye. What is a million years for somebody who has been alive for a trillion? Approximately the same as half an hour for somebody who was alive for sixty. This is the issue with the infinities, we already have problems with visualising anything longer than ~a thousand years, and infinity is so vaster than even the age of the universe...

### So, solution 1: make the souls inhuman psychologically.

Some religions claim that your soul is in fact *not* your consciousness, but instead some vital part of you that you nonetheless have no awareness of. Use it to your advantage, and warp your soul-mind so that it is eternally happy and content - with this you won't even need to do the standard "happy place in white clouds with golden harps" portrayal. It will be more abstract type of heaven, with beings there not even being properly conscious of their state, but it will still be a place of eternal happiness and warmth. I guess that solution will fail if you want the heaven dwellers to be sympathetical, or interact with the living folk - they'd essentially be alien beings for us humans.

### Solution 2: get done with the whole pesky "time" thing

Make it so that in heaven there is no time as humans understand it. It might flow differently, or everything happening all at once, or something even more mind-bending - the core idea is that "infinity of time" is about as nonsensical as "two days" there, souls experience the entirety of infinity simultaneously with no waiting or getting bored (Since boredom is a function of repetition and time). Bonus points in that from their perspective, everyone will appear in heaven at once! No need to wait for your loved ones to finally kick the bucket and join you! But this will still affect their psychology and subjective perceptions, I'm afraid, although this time it maybe easier to retain them sympathetic and human-like.

Answer (score 0):

It's really an hard question with a lot of potential answers, really philosophy and religion related, but there might be some ways to attain your goals? I'll go over three ones I thought of, going from the most satisfying one to the most dodgy one. Sort of, that'just a guess. They all goes on the basis that everyone can reach happiness, which is... not necessarily true, I don't know!

### Help them reach true Enlightenment

*I am no expert at all in Buddhism and I lack all nuances in it, so I can give an excuse hug for anyone who feels hurt about what I am going to say. Just tell if I write something ugly and ask that hug. I only do it with good intentions.*

Product consumation and other materialistic subjects is an intense, but usually fleeting feeling that can lead to a sense of disappointment. The goal is to avoid bounds to material needs and be one with the world but most importantly, be one with oneself. Well, that's very roughly the idea.

If you can get past your internal pulsions through enlightenment, then there's probably no need to do anything to be in a state of at least relaxation and acceptance, at most a state of true happiness. The main problem lies in how to access it, but if you give them a hand, it may work?

There are two warnings that I should raise though : Is it actually possible to reach Enlightenment? If it is, then how much time do you need to actually reach it, and is this an acceptable time loss for a soul to reach eternal happiness?

### Nostal-life

Given they have infinite memory of past events, you may think that they will get bored once they have done everything for the infinitiest of time, but that may not actually hold true.

Think this as an infinite desert, where every drop of water in an oasis, every rock and plants and every grain of sand constitutes something you remember. You know every location in the desert, every grain of sand it contains and go freely anywhere you want, but in the end, you can only look at so many things at once, like you can think about so-many things at one time. To remember a memory, you need to walk in the desert, creating new traces, new memories of remembering things and maybe altering existing memories.

Then, moving back to something can be done only for the purpose of remembering it, to relive the feeling you had at that time. Do you remember the best time you had with a friend? You'd probably want to relive it, and if you don't want to relive it, maybe you want to live the time you remembered how it felt and how you feel about it now?

What I mean is that a memory is different from the feeling it gives back to you at one time. If you get in a quarrel by someone and tell it to your companion in the evening, then you'll probably be angry, but ten years later, this same memory may end up in a laugh, recalling how silly it was at that time.

Note that while remembering things can be pleasant, not all people will feel the same way; They can develop fear of some memories or regrets. Which aren't the best positive feelings in the world :). So in order to work perfectly and prevent all unhappiness, you may need to take out bad memories out of their life, and worse, prevent all bad situations from coming.

### The worlds of my garden are many

Nothing actually limits how many things you can experience in your infinite life. There might be infinite worlds with the same amount of rules and configurations one can think of, we don't know! A universe in which 1+1 = Rocket flower (whatever that means), or one in which gravity is reversed are totally envisageable.

Therefore, if you're not limited to the rules nor the initial setups of the universe, you will never tire out of things to do. If you start to feel the slightest boredom, just hop into another world that a soul guide will be wisely advising you to counter any bad feeling you will have there. Yes, you'll need some kind of railway, because as clever as people are, they are still flawed and may choose activities or places which are not what they are actually interested in, even if they're the only one to be affected.

Yet, one thing to consider : Can you accept that circling from world to world like they were amusement parks would be a morally good thing for your souls?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this becomes a philosophical consideration, namely one of ontology and teleology. If I'm understanding correctly, these souls are selected for "goodness" (from the examples it would appear that this excludes the desire or intent to harm others) and they have access to pleasurable things. In our world of course we primarily perform actions from desire (stemming from will) or necessity.

To elaborate in more classical language humans can be said to have a Telos which is the state of happiness (as understood through contentment, pleasure and self-fulfillment), which in more modern philosophies is recast as self-actualization. Since your souls already are in a state of happiness, this cannot be their Telos.

Instead it would seem that to avoid boredom (which is of course an emotion, philosophically understood in an ultimate sense as nihilism), a new Telos is needed. So while your souls are happy and engaged in pleasurable activities, these actions and their states cannot be the ends in and of themselves.

Practically, this can be interpreted in a nearly infinite amount of ways. Presumably the souls still engage in pleasurable activity in the first place because (even if temporarily) some states are more desirable than others. That is to say that the souls are not in a perpetual state. In this way, there could still be room for adventure, change and growth and "things to do". The only restriction is that they are not performing actions out of necessity but out of will.

Answer (score 0):

## Groundhog Day:

Okay, this question is asking for religious perspective, so here it goes. Maybe Heaven and Hell are the same place, but differing in how you appreciate it and the company you keep.

If you read the bible, the description of Heaven sounds a little dull. It's a lot of basking in the glory of the divine, eternally singing praise, and loving everyone unconditionally. I'd be good with that for about six months. There is no body, not need for fleshy stuff, no material food. So material stimulus isn't an option.

If you read the demands that we love the divine, love each other, and do good constantly as a warning rather than a demand, the whole thing takes on a different tone. Everyone is going to the same place, under the same conditions. Once there, who we are is already pretty much set. So if you are addicted to physical pleasures, hate on everyone constantly, and are generally an unpleasant person, you're going to be miserable. The only people who can tolerate you are similar folks, but you all know how much you despise each other and how miserable you are. Everyone can see every flaw and insult. It's cold, it's bleak, and it will last you forever.

If you spent your formative (living) years trying to make yourself into the kind, loving generous person you could be, you'll get to the other side and it will be GREAT! You find yourself constantly happy, satisfied with the good you did and feeding off the (immaterial) rewards heaven has to offer. You see the stories of turning things around, redemption and forgiveness, and you just love these folks. Basking in the warmth of the hearts and hearths of these folks, you can imagine no better fate than a long and lustrous winter.

I heard an analogy to this once. In Hell, everyone sits at a table filled with the most delicious foods imaginable, but must eat it with enormous cartoonish utensils. Everyone is constantly starving and miserable. Heaven is exactly the same. The difference? In Heaven, everyone feeds everyone else.